# Word and pdf using "create file" action does not open when created by flow - Power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, power-automate, flow, word

I'm trying to generate some word or pdf documents on the fly by using the **Create file** action but I can't get to open the files when its generated inside a document library in SharePoint online.

See below screen shot:

[image]

Error:

[image]

And

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing text content to "File Content" property of **Create file** action will not work in Power automate flow.

As per the documentation, "File Content" property requires input of type **binary** - Content of the file.

**Documentation**: [SharePoint connector - Create file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#create-file)